# Write Python dictionary obtained from JSON in a file

Tags: python, json

I have this script which abstract the json objects from the webpage. The json objects are converted into dictionary. Now I need to write those dictionaries in a file. Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests

r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
for item in r.json or []:
    print item['repository']['name']
```

There are ten lines in a file. I need to write the dictionary in that file which consist of ten lines..How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Wait a second.... why don't you just save the JSON itself?

Comment: I need to save objects in the easiest way possible in to a file..It hasn't be the python dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address the original question, something like:

```
with open("pathtomyfile", "w") as f:
    for item in r.json or []:
        try:
            f.write(item['repository']['name'] + "\n")
        except KeyError:  # you might have to adjust what you are writing accordingly
            pass  # or sth ..
```

note that not every item will be a repository, there are also gist events (etc?).

Better, would be to just save the json to file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import requests

r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')

with open("yourfilepath.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(r.json))
```

then, you can open it:

```
with open("yourfilepath.json", "r") as f:
    obj = json.loads(f.read())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I just save the json into the file. I want to save the returned objects in the easiest way possible. Can you please edit your answer. Thank you.